# Get VPN event ID for Task Scheduler

Tags: automation, task, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, vpn

I'm trying to schedule a task using Task Scheduler based on an event, which would be going on VPN. My company used GlobalProtect for VPN connection. I tried using "RasClient" as Source and 20225 as event ID based on a post I saw online, but unsuccessfully. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation.  I couldn't find an event log trigger for GlobalProtect specifically.  But I did figure out that I could look for the network profile in the Windows event logs for my company's VPN.  Try this...

```
Select 'Triggers' Tab
Click 'New' at bottom of Window
Open 'Begin the task' drop-down
Select 'On an Event'
Configure Event:
Log: 'Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational'
Source: 'NetworkProfile'
Event ID: '10001'
```